# What are we required to do under PPACA if we are retired, living outside of the USA and want to come back for a long visit?

Tags: us-citizens, health-insurance

We are retired, living outside the USA, earning no income and our retirement income is below the level of needing to pay any taxes.  What are the requirements for PPACA if we come back to take care of an aging parent for 2 months?  We realize this will take us out of the 330 day time-frame for being out of the country.

Comment: "We realize this will take us out of the 330 day time-frame for being out of the country. " Not necessarily. If you pick the 12 month period ending about a month into your stay in the U.S., you should be out of the U.S. 330 days in that. Then you also pick the 12 month period starting about a month before you leave the U.S., you should also be out of the U.S. 330 days in that. So those periods would be exempt.

Comment: Also, do you qualify under the Bona Fide Residence Test?

Answer (score 1):

if you do not earn enough income to file taxes, then you are exempt from the individual mandate.  also, if you have medicare coverage, then you satisfy the ppaca requirements.  source:

http://kff.org/infographic/the-requirement-to-buy-coverage-under-the-affordable-care-act/